# How to call json data on code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, web-services

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var LastRecID = 1;
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                    var ImpData = document.getElementById('<%= hdnLanguage.ClientID %>').value;
                    if (LastRecID <= 1)
                        sendData();
                    LastRecID++;
                }
            });

            function sendData() {

                $.ajax(
                 {
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "try.aspx/GetData",
                     data: ImpData ,
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",
                     async: "true",
                     cache: "true",

                     success: function (msg) {
                         $("#myDiv").append(msg.d);
                     },

                     Error: function (x, e) {
                         alert("err");
                     }

                 });

            }

        });


    </script>
```

I have hidden Field and it has same value. I set ImpData for hdnLanguage

```
 var ImpData = document.getElementById('<%= hdnLanguage.ClientID %>').value;
```

I send data with Json:

```
data: ImpData
```

But I dont know how to call this data (ImpData) on code behind(in static web service). Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` are translated to the `GetData` parameters. You if you send `data` like this:

```
data: { param1: ImpData }
```

Your `GetData` method has to have at least the `param1` parameter:

```
public static void GetData(string param1)
```

Comment: it doesnt work, i couldnt call web service when the add paramater

Answer (score 0):

I find answer

Json:

```
data: "{'Param': '" + Param + "'}"
```

Code Behind:

```
public static string GetData(string Param)
{

....

}
```